# can switch make lan slow

Tags: switch, router, troubleshooting

i have network in my office which i roughly described in images.
pc1(Ethernet) and laptop(via wifi) is connected directly to router, and pc2 and pc3 is connected via switch in both in Ethernet.

when i transfer data between laptop and pc1 it works fine, but when i trying to transfer between pc2 or pc3 to pc1 process becomes too much slow.

is using switch making this lan slow or is there any extra configuration is to make to work this?

[image]

Comment: You should edit your question to provide more detail. Include things like the device models and configurations. Without the detail we are just left to guess where the problem may lie.

Comment: What speed are the switches ?

Answer (score 1):

Using a switch does not make a network slow. In fact, in most cases, it makes it faster since switches provide separate bandwidth per interface and many collision domains. Only when it comes to broadcasts do switches prove inferior (assuming without vlan, etc) since it has only one broadcast domain. Routers are only used in the case of linking two different networks.

As for your problem, I would suggest checking the cabling you're using with the switch. You should be using a straight through cable for switch to host connections (length of the cable also matters). Usually, slowness with a switch is attributed to duplex or speed mismatches between two devices. However, to zero into your problem, we'll need some interface information of your switch (maybe a show interfaces f0/0?)

Answer (score 1):

A properly functioning switch should not make the network slow. The key is in the words "properly functioning".

When dealing with cheap consumer network hardware the first thing to try is power cycling everything.

The second thing to check is that on any equipment that supports configuring speed and duplex mode (unmanaged switches and home routers will probablly be in autonegotiate mode whether you like it or not) that the ports are set up correctly. Connecting a port set to forced full duplex to a port set to autonegotiate or forced half duplex will result in excruciatinly slow communications.

The third thing to check is the cabling. Make sure you don't have split pairs. If possible bring the equipment together into one room and hook it up with short patch cables.

if all of that fails it's probablly time to consider swapping out equipment.

P.S. I've found windows file sharing often suffers from weird speed problems when nothing else does. I have no idea why.